# Indesign SDK - Model and UI Plugin

Tags: visual-c++, plugins, sdk, adobe-indesign

How to use a **model plugin** in **UI plugin** of **Indesign SDK**. And how to separate the model and UI plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the InDesign plug-in programming guide by simple google search. There are PDF versions available. The one to explain this specific doubt is available [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/plugin/plugin-programming-guide-vol1.pdf).
Chapter 5 has a detailed discussion on model and ui plug-ins and model and UI separation.